# How to filter data/conect on a grid view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am making an ordering website as part of an assignment. A doctor logs in and sees all the orders put forward by his patients. When the doctor clicks some check boxes and clicks the button - the boxes that are checked update the orders (rows) column (approve) to approved. The unchecked boxes update the approve column to disapproved - this all works and updates...

however the grid does not disappear after this - the doctor can keep updating the orders and changing them but I want only the new orders that have not been checked/unchecked to appear. - I dont know how to apply this to my vb code.

I dont want the orders to delete from the database order table - just present the new orders to the doctor that he has not yet checked/unchecked.

my gird:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewdoc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="OrderId">
     <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" HeaderText="Order Id" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorId" HeaderText="Doctor Id" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Forename" HeaderText="Forename" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="MedicineId" HeaderText="Medicine Id" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="MedicineName" HeaderText="Medicine Name" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="pharmname" HeaderText="Pharmacy Name" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Dateordered" HeaderText="Date Ordered" />
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve Status"> 
  <ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:CheckBox   ID="ApproveBox" runat="server"  /> 
  </ItemTemplate> 
   </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

my code behind gid:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Imports System.Data

Partial Class Pages_docorders
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        Dim cmd3string As String = " Select * From docgridview  WHERE DoctorId = " & Session("DoctorId")
        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
        Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd3string, conn)
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)
        conn.Close()



        GridViewdoc.DataSource = dt
        GridViewdoc.DataBind()

    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub GridViewdoc_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridViewdoc.RowDataBound


    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim drview As DataRowView = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)

        'Find checkbox and checked/Unchecked based on values
        Dim chkb As CheckBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ApproveBox"), CheckBox)
        If drview(8).ToString() = "Approve" Then
            chkb.Checked = True
        Else
        End If
    End If

End Sub
Protected Sub btnapprove_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnapprove.Click
    Dim dt As Data.DataTable = Session("Approved")
    Dim val As String
    val = ""
    Dim Oid As Integer
    Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridViewdoc.Rows
        Dim therowindex As Integer = row.RowIndex
        Oid = Integer.Parse(GridViewdoc.DataKeys(therowindex).Value.ToString())
        val = ""
        Dim cb As CheckBox = row.FindControl("ApproveBox")
        If cb.Checked Then

            val = "Approved"
        Else

            val = "Disapproved"
        End If
        If Oid > 0 Then
            Dim cmdstring As String = " UPDATE Order_pres SET Approved = @appr  Where OrderID= @oid"
            conn.Close()
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@appr", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = val
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@oid", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Oid
            Dim result As Integer
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End If
    Next

    Dim cmd3string As String = " Select * From docgridview  WHERE DoctorId = " & Session("DoctorId")
    Dim dtm As New System.Data.DataTable()
    Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd3string, conn)
    conn.Close()
    conn.Open()
    da.Fill(dtm)
    conn.Close()
    GridViewdoc.DataSource = dtm
    GridViewdoc.DataBind()
End Sub
```

End Class

Hopefully someone can help  - thank you :)

Comment: The title says that you want to hide the GridView but, in fact, you want to filter its content. Is that correct?

Comment: Hello @ConnorsFan! yes indeed this is what I am trying to do

Comment: @ConorsFan - I have edited the title, do you know how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Approved` field is `NULL` in `Order_pres` as long as no decision has been made about the order approval, you could try this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindGridViewData()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btnapprove_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnapprove.Click
    ...
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridViewdoc.Rows
        ...
    Next
    BindGridViewData()
End Sub

Protected Sub BindGridViewData()
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT DGV.* FROM docgridview DGV INNER JOIN Order_pres OP ON OP.OrderID = DGV.OrderID WHERE DGV.DoctorId = @DoctorId AND OP.Approved IS NULL", conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DoctorId", Session("DoctorId")))
            Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dtm As New DataTable()
            dataAdapter.Fill(dtm)
            GridViewdoc.DataSource = dtm.DefaultView
            GridViewdoc.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

The query looks for records in `docgridview` for which the corresponding record in `Order_pres` has not been approved or disapproved yet.

N.B. The code above assumes that the following lines are present at the top of your VB code file:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Comment: Hi @ConnorsFan! thank you for your answer - I have updated the code in my question to all of the code behind file, could you show me where that part goes please :)

Comment: I updated my answer to show that the code replaces the end of the event handler for `btnapprove.Click` (from `Dim cmd3string As String...` to the end of the method).

Comment: this works - the grid disappears when the button is clicked - but it reappears when I reload the page/ login again  is there a way to only show orders that are like new (havnt been checked) but they still remain on the order table

Comment: would this work somewhere on the select statement - select * from order_pres where Approved = ""  or null ?

Comment: You say "this works - the grid disappears". You want the same when you reload the page?

Comment: it disappears but the person controlling the order shouldnt see the orders already dealt with every time they log in - can this be done?

Comment: I modified the answer to use the same code to fill the GridView when loading the page and after clicking the Approve button. If you don't see any data, it should be because all the records have been approved/disapproved for that doctor.

Comment: great answer @connorsfan